# Does the ASP.NET MVC AjaxHelper deal with degradation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, deprecated

Does anyone know if the AjaxHelper in the ASP.NET MVC framework deals with degradation?

For example, if you have an ActionLink that updates the content of a div, if JavaScript unavailable, will the page do a full postback by renderubg the page (via an action on a controller) and call the action specified in the ActionLink?

If not, how would you suggest making a page function correctly for browsers with JavaScript enabled and those who have it disabled within the context of an MVC app?

Comment: I had a similar question the other day see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320135/aspnet-mvc-json-non-js-clients)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is in your controller, override the OnActionExecuted method and change the filerContext.ActionResult for non-JavaScript enabled browsers. You can also add you own ActionFilters to different actions in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an `Url` parameter to the `AjaxOptions` object to the `Ajax.ActionLink` call:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(role, "GetPeopleData",
    new { selectedRole = role },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "tbody",
        Url = Url.Action("GetPeopleData", new { selectedRole = role })
    })
```